# WP7 AdMob No Requests

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I'm trying to implement the AdMob SDK into my WP7 app.  I followed the directions, but I don't get any ads, not even test ads.  I traced the network traffic with fiddler and see that the AdMob JS is downloaded, but I never see any HTTP requests for any ads.  Anyone see this, or know how to fix it?

Comment: I had a similar issue and couldn't really find a solution. Is there a reason you are using Admob over AdControl (PubCenter)? If the only reason is because you like google, I'd try the MS control. They just released a patch for it that made it behave a lot smoother. Others have suggested using a third party control like http://www.aldarit.com/superads.html or something. I wish the AdMob control behaved better.

Comment: PubCenter has decreased the eCPM and payouts by 50% month over month for the past 3 months.  My impressions are staying constant, so I'm trying to explore other options.

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's kbown problem, try 3G

http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/68ea6c16b194bc1f/26f2232a7681f786?lnk=gst&q=phone+7#26f2232a7681f786