# admob ad doesn't make requests (or there are no ads to show)

Tags: windows-phone-7, admob

I just downloaded the Beta sdk for admob on WP7 and after including the banner in the app(and viewing the default banner in the emulator mode) i've added the admob on-site publisher id an tried to run the app on a real device but there was no add showed (in debug and in release mode). The space is reserved (~75px of black space).

When looking in the console i see "`Error - Ad Not Available (NoFill)`" and on the admob site i see that there wasn't no ad request ever made. I got to the following conclusions:

1) there are no ads for my app due to windows phone's still-limited presence (but why isn't my app showing ad requests on admob site?). Also i found this on google's site :

> Windows Phone 7 is new to the AdMob market, so in the short term you
>   may see some low fill rates until advertisers add this platform to
>   their targeting. Using test mode during development should eliminate
>   inventory as a variable in your SDK integration testing.

2)i've just created my admob ad so maybe google has a certain approval process.

Any other ideas of this problem? Has anyone else experinced it, and if so, how did they get over it?

**UPDATE** my app is now active on the adMob site and can see requests (122) , a fill rate(3.28%), eCPM(0), RPM(0) but the ads are still not showing. What can be the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719064/wp7-admob-no-requests